# How to resolve class with constructor that has List<T> parameter?

Tags: c#, generics, autofac

I have a class as below, which constructor takes in two `List<T>`

```
public  class Param<T>
{
    public List<T> Joes { get; }
    public List<T> Dans { get; }

    public Param(List<T> joes, List<T> dans)
    {
        Joes = joes;
        Dans = dans;
    }
}
```

I try to register and resolve this object,

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    var builder = new ContainerBuilder();
    builder.RegisterType<int>().As<object>();
    builder.RegisterGeneric(typeof(Param<>));
    var container = builder.Build();
    var paramHaha = container.Resolve<Param<object>>();
}
```

I got this exception

> An error occurred during the activation of a particular registration.
>   See the inner exception for details. Registration: Activator = Param'1
>   (ReflectionActivator), Services =
>   [ConsoleApplication2.Param'1[[System.Int32, mscorlib, Version=4.0.0.0,
>   Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089]]], Lifetime =
>   Autofac.Core.Lifetime.CurrentScopeLifetime, Sharing = None, Ownership
>   = OwnedByLifetimeScope ---> None of the constructors found with 'Autofac.Core.Activators.Reflection.DefaultConstructorFinder' on type
>   'ConsoleApplication2.Param'1[System.Int32]' can be invoked with the
>   available services and parameters:\r\nCannot resolve parameter
>   'System.Collections.Generic.List'1[System.Int32] joes' of constructor
>   'Void .ctor(System.Collections.Generic.List'1[System.Int32],
>   System.Collections.Generic.List'1[System.Int32])'. (See inner
>   exception for details.)"}

How can I fix this problem? I don't really care what is the object I get for `Param`, and I don't care about what the `T` is.  The `Param` is just an dummy object to be used elsewhere. But I need to get it properly initialized.

Comment: What should be injected for `joes` and `dans`? A random list?

Comment: @YacoubMassad , yes.

Comment: If you don't care what is injected for those two lists - just create parameterless constructor for that Param.

Comment: @Evk , assume  that I cannot create parameterless constructor for whatever reason.

Comment: It seems to me you are abusing your DI container to build up object graphs of objects containing runtime state. That's not where DI container's are meant for. Their job is to build up object graphs of application components. Components are the classes that contain the application's behavior, not the data.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order to specify parameters value at registration time, you may want to use the `WithParameter` method :

```
builder.RegisterGeneric(typeof(Param<>))
       .As(typeof(Param<>))
       .WithParameter(new ResolvedParameter(
           (pi, ctx) => pi.Name == "joes",
           (pi, ctx) => /* Get joes with pi.ParameterType */));
```

the second parameter of `ResolveParameter` is a lambda that will give the value of the parameter. Because you use generic version of `Param` you have to use the `pi.ParameterType` property to get the value of the right type.

See [Passing Parameters to Register](http://docs.autofac.org/en/latest/register/parameters.html) for more information

In order to avoid having the `joes` retrieving logic in your dependency injection registration process, you can implement a `JoeProvider`

```
public interface IJoeProvider 
{
    List<Object> GetJoes(); 
}
public interface IJoeProvider<T> : IJoeProvider
{
    List<T> GetJoes(); 
}


builder.RegisterGeneric(typeof(JoeProvider<>)
       .As(typeof(IJoeProvider<>)); 
builder.RegisterGeneric(typeof(Param<>))
       .As(typeof(Param<>))
       .WithParameter(new ResolvedParameter(
           (pi, ctx) => pi.Name == "joes",
           (pi, ctx) => {
               Type t = typeof(IJoeProvider<>).MakeGenericType(pi.ParameterType); 
               IJoeProvider p = (IJoeProvider)ctx.Resolve(t); 
               return p.GetJoes(); 
           }));
```

Of course, in order to avoid having a `JoeProvider` and `DanProvider` you can have only one `Provider` and resolving it with a parameter.

```
public interface IParamProvider 
{
    List<Object> GetParams(); 
}
public interface IParamProvider<T> : IParamProvider
{
    List<T> GetParams(); 
}
public class ParamProvider<T> : IParamProvider<T>
{
    public ParamProvider(String paramName)
    {
        this._paramName = paramName;
    }
    private readonly String _paramName;

    // Do IParamProviderProvider implementation
}


builder.RegisterGeneric(typeof(ParamProvider<>)
       .As(typeof(IParamProvider<>)); 
builder.RegisterGeneric(typeof(Param<>))
       .As(typeof(Param<>))
       .WithParameter(new ResolvedParameter(
           (pi, ctx) => pi.ParameterType.IsGenericType 
                        && pi.ParameterType.GetGenericTypeDefinition() == typeof(List<>),
           (pi, ctx) => {
               Type t = typeof(IParamProvider<>).MakeGenericType(pi.ParameterType); 
               IParamProvider p = (IParamProvider)ctx.Resolve(t, new NamedParameter("paramName", pi.Name)); 
               return p.GetParams(); 
           }));
```

Answer (score 1):

You can register class together with parameters, like this:

```
builder.RegisterGeneric(typeof(Param<>)).WithParameters(
    new [] {TypedParameter.From<object>(null), TypedParameter.From<object>(null)});
```

This will just pass nulls as `joes` and `dans` in your case.